# Estimating Titan X graphics card impact on performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, performance, gpu

I'm currently training CNNs using Tensorflow (Python) on my GTX 970 (specs [here](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-970/specifications)). I recently took a look at the new pascal based [Titan Xs](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/titan-x-pascal/) and I'm wondering what an estimated performance/speed gain would be if I upgraded?

The memory increase is an obvious benefit for larger models, but I'm mostly wondering about speed.

Does the doubling of core count and bump in memory speed offer that much of a performance gain? Anyone have any experience with the new (or old) Titan X cards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of parameters which matter when using GPU's for machine learning, some of them are:

1. CUDA core count
2. Memory bandwidth (GB/s)
3. Memory per core (MB)
4. Raw Speed (MHz)
5. Total Memory available (GB)
6. Performance on 16-bit, 32-bit floating ops/sec

[Tim Dettmers](http://timdettmers.com/2014/08/14/which-gpu-for-deep-learning/) has an excellent (frequently updated) blog where he's compared different cards, near the end he's also given a simple speed-up comparison. Using that as a guide, it can be estimated that Titan X pascal would be upto 5 times faster than a GTX 970 for Deep Learning.